# JPA/JPQL: Fill a collection/map based on related object's collection/map? (prototype-like)

Tags: hibernate, select, jpa, jpql, prototypal-inheritance

I have such structure of entities:

```
Product  1 -> N   ProductCustomField
  1                       1
  |                       |
  M                       M'
Release  1 -> N'  ReleaseCustomField
```

`ProductCustomField` is kind of "prototype" - a list of fields which Release may have.

I'd like to select a single `Release` object with all `ReleaseCustomFields` whose `ProductCustomField` are in the `Product` of which the `Release` is.

**Example:**

MySoft has custom field "downloadURL" with default value "".
MySoft has release 1.0.
This release has no ReleaseCustomFields, but because it is a release of MySoft, I can tell that it may have "downloadURL" custom field.

So I would like to have MySoft 1.0 release with a map where "downloadURL" would be defined (with a default value "").

I know what would I do in SQL, it would be a nice long complex SELECT, but possible.
I don't know though how to grasp it in JPA/Hibernate.

Not sure if this is the right thing to try to achieve in `SELECT`.
Maybe I should rather fill the `Release`'s custom fields with an INSERT and then simply rely on mapping (which already works)?
Or should I create a special property in `Release`, filled with special query? (I don't mind using `org.hibernate.*` annotations.)
Or should I do the simplest thing - take `release.getProduct().getCustomFields()` and do "for each field in `ProductCustomField`, use what's in `ReleaseCustomField`, or `ProductCustomField#getDefault()` otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

I have chosen the third approach. Since I use the Wicket framework, I have created a Model which, given a `release` and `release.getProduct.getCustomFields().get("fieldName")` is capable of getting either default value, or the actual value, and when written to, updates `releases`' field values map.

I started getting `IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class` but that's most likely a different problem.