# Hibernate bug? Mishandling result columns, querying the DB for nonexistent ID

Tags: hibernate, jpa, foreign-keys, fetch

I observe a weird behavior of Hibernate.

I have an entity graph described in [JPA/JPQL: Fill a collection/map based on related object's collection/map? (prototype-like)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14493642/jpa-jpql-fill-a-collection-map-based-on-related-objects-collection-map)

Then I query this model:

```
this.em.createQuery("SELECT rel FROM Release rel "
            + " LEFT JOIN FETCH rel.product pr "
            + "   LEFT JOIN FETCH pr.customFields "
            + " LEFT JOIN FETCH rel.customFields "
            + (withDeps ? " LEFT JOIN FETCH rel.deps" : "")
            + " WHERE rel.product.name = ?1 AND rel.version = ?2", Release.class)
            .setParameter(1, prodName)
            .setParameter(2, version)
            .getSingleResult();
```

Hibernate converts this into two queries:

```
select release0_.id as rel, product1_.id as prod, customfiel2_.id as prodCF, customfiel3_.id as relCF,  
release0_.product_id as rel_prod, ...
from `release` release0_  
left outer join product product1_ on release0_.product_id=product1_.id  
left outer join prod_custField customfiel2_ on product1_.id=customfiel2_.product_id  
left outer join rel_custField customfiel3_ on release0_.id=customfiel3_.release_id  
cross join product product4_  
where release0_.product_id=product4_.id and product4_.name='EAP' and release0_.version='6.0.1.GA'
```

Which returns

'1', '1', '3', '2', '1', '4', ...

And then

```
select productcus0_.id as id59_0_, productcus0_.label as label59_0_, productcus0_.name as name59_0_ from prod_custField productcus0_ where productcus0_.id=1;
```

The problem is that Hibernate loads ProductCustomField with id "1", which is a bug - because none of the returned columns refers to PCF; there's one ID "1" which corresponds to ReleaseCustomField.

Here's the result minus irrelevant text fields:

```
{
    'rel' : 1,
    'prod' : 1,
    'prodCF' : 3,
    'relCF' : 2,
    'rel_prodid' : 1,
    'status' : 4,
    'prodCFname' : 'jarRpmLic',
    'prodCF_prodid' : 1,
    'prodCF_id' : 3,
    'prodCF_name' : 'jarRpmLic',
    'relCF_id' : 1,
    'relCF_name' : 'eapCustField1',
    'relCF_relid' : 1,
    'relCF_val' : 'wdqdwqwdqd',
    'relCF_relID' : 1,
    'relCF_id' : 2,
    'relCF_name' : 'eapCustField1'
}
```

As you can see, the only value usable for ProductCustomField is 3.

Is this a bug? How should I verify? What would be the workaround? I consider using some Hibernate-specific @Fetch strategy, or hydrating the entity partially and load the other collections manually via another DAO call.

Stacktrace:

```
javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find org.jboss.essc.web.model.ProductCustomField with id 1
 at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration$Ejb3EntityNotFoundDelegate.handleEntityNotFound(Ejb3Configuration.java:155)
 at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:210)
 at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:260)
 at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:148)
 at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1079)
 at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1006)
 at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:613)
 at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:441)
 at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:168)
 at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:134)
 at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:999)
 at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:878)
 at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:293)
 at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2382)
 at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2368)
 at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2198)
 at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2193)
 at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:470)
 at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:355)
 at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:195)
 at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1248)
 at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
 at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:285)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be caused by HHH-6361 and HHH-7928 and I overlooked inconsistent data. 
I relied on that FK constraints would warn me, but the particular one was missing.

```
HHH-6361
```

Collection events may contain wrong stored snapshot after merging a detached entity into the persistencecontext